# When is inline confirmation necessary and when is it not?

Tags: usability, confirmation, best-practice

I have a scenario where the user is asked to select one of two or more options and then accordingly enter into another page. After selecting the desired option, should there be a secondary section which asks the user to confirm and proceed with the selected option?

Proceeding directly on selection of the option costs one click whereas the scenario which seeks an additional confirmation costs two clicks.

Which one is the better approach?

By the way, the user can change his selection later inside the app by accessing a dropdown from a static location.

Comment: Initial thoughts are to go with a single click, if the option can be changed later, however, there's no a lot of information here to go on.

Comment: If the change is not permanent, maybe add a label (perhaps in a tooltip behind an info/help icon) which says that the choice can be changed later.

Comment: "user is asked to select one of two or more options" how are that options selected? by which control? A screenshot would help!

Answer (score 2):

A rule of thumb is: **What is the impact of an incorrect choice?**

Consider

- Is change permanent or reversible
- What is value of loss if any (this includes users time and data)
- Is it easy to rectify
- Is it clear what choice was made and the implications

Impact ranges from
*Negligible* (no permanent change, zero value loss, very easy to rectify; no chance of confusion about system state) to *Critical*  (permanent impact; loss of life; action impossible to reverse; indeterminate state)

So range of confirmations required vary from none to nuclear launch fail-safe mechanisms.

One consideration is don't over-estimate novice users ability to both understand the system state and discover the settings menu.